# How do you generate the output of for loop and if statement into a list or vector?

Tags: r, nested-for-loop

I have tried the following but the output brings an argument stating,

```
Error in append("0") : argument "values" is miss
```

```
  for (rowz in final_data$Ingridients) {
  Cobalt_row<-lst()
  if (sum(str_detect(rowz, 'Cobalt'))>0) {
    Cobalt_row.append(1)
  } else {
    Cobalt_row<-append(0)
  }
  print(Cobalt_row)
}
```

I intended to loop through the list and generate a boolean of ones and twos depending on
whether or not I had the value.

Please help

Comment: Please provide reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Without the data, I can't test it, but this should work:

```r
Cobalt_row<-lst()
k <- 1
for (rowz in final_data$Ingridients) {
  Cobalt_row[[k]] <- ifelse(str_detect(rowz, 'Cobalt'), 1, 0)
  k <- k+1
}
```

or even simpler if you need a list:

```r
Cobalt_row <- as.list(as.numeric(str_detect(final_data$Ingredients, "Cobalt")))
```